# When is it good practice to use \unskip

Tags: spacing, tex-core

One sees in `source2e` the command `\unskip` used in various places. My understanding in general terms is that the macro is the equivalent of `\ignorespacesbehind`.

Where would it be recommended to use `\unskip`?

MWE for experimentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\def\test{\leavevmode \unskip test  }
\def\testa{\leavevmode test\ignorespaces  }

\test testing  \test 

\testa testing  \testa test
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the first occurrence of `\test`, `\unskip` does nothing, because no skip is there; in the second it removes the space after `testing` (two spaces are normalized to one space token). The `\ignorespaces` in the two occurrences of `\testa` does nothing, because no space token is found.

Comment: @egreg Sharp eye:)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In addition to @Josephs's points, things to be aware of:

- `\unskip` acts on horizontal and vertical space, so it will remove *vertical* space if used between paragraphs.
- Unlike `\ignorespaces` which affects the conversion between input characters and tokens, `\unskip` works on the actual lists inside boxes, after all tokenisation and commands have been executed.
- `\unskip` can not be used in outer vertical mode: Once an item has been added to the main vertical list of a page it can not be removed. So while in a minipage you can remove preceding vertical space with `\unskip`, on the main page you have to use `\vskip-\lastskip` to back up over the previous skip rather than actually removing it. This leaves  breakable glue so you may also need to inject some `\penalties` to prevent page breaking.

---

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\setbox0\vbox{

\hbox{g}

\vskip 10pt

\hbox{b}
}

\showbox0


\setbox2\vbox{

\hbox{g}

\vskip 10pt

\unskip\nobreak\hbox{b}
}

\showbox2

\setbox4\vbox{

\hbox{g}

\vskip 10pt

\vskip-\lastskip\nobreak\hbox{b}
}

\showbox2


\hbox{g}

\vskip 10pt

\unskip\nobreak\hbox{b}


\stop
```

Box 0 is

```
\vbox(26.30554+0.0)x5.55557
.\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x5.00002
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.\glue 10.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x5.55557
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
```

But suppose (as in box 2) That the code adding `b` needs to remove space above, it could use `\unskip` which literally removes it, resulting in

```
\vbox(16.30554+0.0)x5.55557
.\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x5.00002
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x5.55557
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
```

If instead of removing it, negative space is added to compensate as n box 4 then you get

```
\vbox(16.30554+0.0)x5.55557
.\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x5.00002
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.\glue 10.0
.\glue -10.0
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x5.55557
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
```

This looks the same but if the penalty was not 10000 then it would be a feasible breakpoint at that position, which means that if the list was unboxed the end of the first part would have depth 0 rather than the depth of `g` which can have subtle (or not so subtle) affects on positioning that are hard to correct (or at least hard to remember to correct).

So the issues surrounding `\unskip` are a lot simpler than the `vskip-\lastskip` combination, however if you are not in a box, you don't have a choice, as the last version on the main page produces:

```
! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
l.46 \unskip
```

Comment: David, will you please expand a bit on the \vskip-\lastskip and what sort of penalties one has to add?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I feared you'd ask that (see also [Marco's follow on question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104043/what-does-list-mean-in-relation-to-skip-what-is-david-on-about) trouble is the penalties depend on the context (and in general you can't add them) I'll try to add something coherent in a bit

Comment: @YiannisLazarides some examples added.

Answer (score 20):

The `\unskip` primitive will remove the last skip from the current list, which includes the common case of a space at the start of some text. Thus `\unskip` is used where you want to allow some flexibility in the input syntax. For example, it's used in some of the centring code to avoid a space at the start of a line messing up the alignment.

Important notes:

- `\unskip` will remove only the last skip, so `\space\space\unskip` will still have one space present.
- `\unskip` does not remove kerns, so `\space\kern0pt\unskip` will not remove the space: this may used deliberately to avoid loosing 'required' spaces.

Comment: What does the following code do: `\space\space\unskip\unskip`? Will it gobble both `\space`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel effectively yes (although it works on the glue items in the list, not on the `\space` tokens)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What does "list" mean in this contents? How can I imagine this list? Sorry but this is an interesting topic and I am not familiar with ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I was just wondering about explaining the character/token/list distinction in the "what is a token" question asked this morning but it doesn't really fit there either. Can't really fit it in a comment I mean what you get in the log if you add `\showoutput` to your document. (perhaps a new question is called for, but It might be a duplicate if I see a link I'll add it here)